# How to paint text directly onto a JFrame without using a Jpanel in Java?

Tags: java, swing, dialog, jframe, paint

I know you are able to modify paintcomponent in order to paint to a Jpanel, however I am trying to make a simple dialog box and do not desire for any of the minimize or maximize buttons to be on the frame (hence why it's undecorated), and do not want the buttons that come with using JPanel or JOptionPane to be on it either. If any of you know how to make an undecorate JPanel to add that would work as well, but if you know how to make drawString paint onto a JFrame that would be nice as well. Here is how far I have gotten so far, if any of you could explain why its not actually drawing the string to the JFrame that would be helpful. 
http://pastebin.com/vfSCnaF7

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a JLabel?

```
    JLabel l = new JLabel("Text");
    frame.add(l);
```

Or do you need the exact positioning you get with drawString()?

Comment: Well, you see I had tried doing that before and it wasn't working, but I just realized i had setvisisibile(true) before using addlabel... XD Thank you very much!

Comment: Ahh... yep, that usually causes problems. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not override the `paint()` method.

You can add a `JPanel` and still have an undecorated window.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that you could still have an undecorated window with JPanel (we literally had a semester of training in java, our teacher is making us make a game for our exam, and I got stuck with making an entire GUI without being able to use JOption Pane). However I think I'll just go with the label that RobotKarel suggested. :)